# Starting over with quicken

Tags: quicken

My quicken accounts have gotten broken somehow. I now have two bank accounts for the same real account. One I can pay bills out of (ie the account that 'send online payment' works from and has all my historical data) and one that current bank statements download into.

I am going to set up a different login on my pc and start over from scratch. Assuming that works, what is the best way to export from my old accounts and import into the new account?

I can 'File - save a copy as qdf' or I can 'backup' and then restore. Has anyone done something like this before? What would you recommend?

Comment: Depending on how many transactions there are in the account you want to eliminate, you could try using the "Move Transaction" command to move all transactions into the desired account, and then edit the Automatic Download settings so that newer transactions download into the desired account. Saving a file as qdf and opening a new login etc just postpones the inevitable merger of the two accounts.

Comment: the problem isn't the merger (I recognize that) - it's the bizzare behavior that I can only pay out of one and download into the second (even of the transactions that were paid out of the first account). So moving only fixes 'last months' problems - they happen all over again next month.

Comment: I suggest you ask the moderators to move this question to a stackexchange site devoted to programming issues. This seems not to be a question about personal finance and money but rather an issue  with the interface between two programs: Quicken running on your machine and your bank's software.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This isn't a programming question.  The OP is a user of the program, not a developer of it.

Comment: There is an **open meta discussion about tools** at http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-technical-questions-about-tools-belong .. if you have an opinion about these kinds of questions being on- or off-topic, please answer or vote there. Thanks!

Comment: Duncan - did you want to come defend the question in meta?  I think we are going to close it, but I would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the account that is currently downloading the transactions:

1. Make a backup.
2. Unsubscribe from One Step Update for both
   accounts.
3. Change the bank account number on both accounts to
   something else
4. Add a new checking account and set up a new One
   Step Update
5. Verify you can import transactions and write checks
   from the new account
6. You can cut and paste the transactions that
   are not duplicated from the historical accounts to the new one.

I hope this helps.